# http call for ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to loop through a collection of endpoints, fire off a get request and if its successful show a good status, Otherwise show a bad status.
It's effectively a health check for endpoints to make sure they are up and running.
The test endpoints:

```
    var endpoints = [{
        "description": "test 1",
        "environment": "global",
        "url":"http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    }, {
        "description": "test 2",
        "environment": "global",
        "url": "http://www.letsPretendThisWillFail.com"
    }];
```

The html

```
<tbody ng-init="getEndpoints()" ng-repeat="e in endpoints" my-repeat-directive>
<tr>
    <td>{{e.description}}</td>
    <td>{{e.environment}}</td>
    <td>
        <i ng-show="canPing(e.url)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart green"></i>
        <i ng-show="!canPing(e.url)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart red"></i>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Check Service" ng-click="canPing(e.url)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> 
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The controller:

```
$scope.canPing = function (e) {

    HealthService
    .testConnection(e)
    .then(success, error);

      function success(response) {
      return true;
      };

    function error(response) {
      return false;
      };
    }
```

My predicament, the canPing function works on it own when called through a ng-click,
However, when it loads the page, the ng-repeat seems to recurse so much my browser breaks.
I'm sure the problem will be resolved using $q but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: 1. `canPing ` does not actually return true/false as it gets a promise from `testConnection` and then has a call back for succes/error. 2. You should cache the results of the callback back to the `endpoint` object that was tested and refer to that. The reason is that it is now being called multiple times (2x in the ng-if) and then gain any time there is a change to the array as the whole thing would be rebound and thus reiterated over.

Comment: **never** put  functions in the view that trigger asynchronous requests unless they are event driven

Comment: @Igor actually a lot more than 2 times due to how digest cycles work